# '' is not a recognized value for UIUserInterfaceStyle

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, darkmode

I'm using

```
<key>UIUserInterfaceStyle</key>
<string>Light</string>
```

to set the UI mode of my app to only ever be in Light mode. However, I keep getting this error:

```
[UIInterfaceStyle] '' is not a recognized value for UIUserInterfaceStyle. Defaulting to Light.
```

Because of this, when I export, Xcode is preventing me from publishing the app and is asking me to write something in the ''. Please help!

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but your Info.plist has User Interface Style set as Light for both Debug and Release, correct? Where are you getting the error you mentioned?

Comment: I think you should recheck your info.plist again maybe the value "Light" is missing

Answer (score 1):

The error means that the value is UIUserInterfaceStyle is "" so it gets the default value which is Light.
It can be caused by you add wrong info.plist which your apps have lots of info.plist or the value is blank which connect to the key UIUserInterfaceStyle. You should use Eng keyboard when typing to Info.plist because sometimes it got error then return blank in value.

Recheck your info.plist again and be sure of your info.plist of the app have value.
[image: Example below]

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, when I would add and change the key & value for Appearance on the list shown when clicking on the place with the X (see below), it would only add the KEY to the (other?) list shown when clicking on the menu item with the arrow pointing to it. So, I had to go into that list (the one with the arrow) and change the value, even though I had changed it on the (other?) list. Weird.

[image: the referenced screenshot]